# I can't extract href from html webpage

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to fetch data from this [webpage](https://www.worldathletics.org/records/all-time-toplists/sprints/100-metres/outdoor/women/senior?regionType=world&timing=electronic&windReading=regular&page=1&bestResultsOnly=false&firstDay=1899-12-31&lastDay=2023-01-21).

I'm relatively new to this. I need to get the href link of the next page button <kbd>></kbd> but can't find the solution.

Please help

Tried this in the terminal

```
response.xpath('//a[@class="btn--pagination btn--pag-next pag-control"]/@href').extract()
```

but it just gives me `[]`.

This is the html code of the button:

```
data-page="2" data-url="http://www.worldathletics.org/records/all-time-toplists/sprints/100-metres/outdoor/women/senior?regionType=world&amp;timing=electronic&amp;windReading=regular&amp;page=1&amp;bestResultsOnly=false&amp;firstDay=1899-12-31&amp;lastDay=2023-01-20" class="btn--pagination btn--pag-next pag-control" href="//www.worldathletics.org/records/all-time-toplists/sprints/100-metres/outdoor/women/senior?regionType=world&amp;timing=electronic&amp;windReading=regular&amp;page=2&amp;bestResultsOnly=false&amp;firstDay=1899-12-31&amp;lastDay=2023-01-20" style="">
                &gt;
            </a>
```

Comment: When i do it i get `//*[@id="toplists"]/div[1]/div/a[260]` and `/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/a[260]` with the full version.

Comment: Have you tried going into Devtools > Inspect > Right click on the selected element > Copy > Copy XPath?

Comment: Yes, already tried that but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: In the html code of the button, the class is `class="btnA btnB pagC"`, so these are actually three classes applied to the button.  Maybe this will help: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#when-querying-by-class-consider-using-css.  Cheers! z

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the link element doesn't have an `href` attribute. use the `data-url` instead

```
response.xpath('//a[@class="btn--pagination btn--pag-next pag-control"]/@data-url').get()
```

OUTPUT

```
'http://worldathletics.org/records/all-time-toplists/sprints/100-metres/outdoor/women/senior?regionType=world&timing=electronic&windReading=regular&page=1&bestResultsOnly=false&firstDay=1899-12-31&lastDay=2023-01-21'
```

Comment: I did inspect the element and it shows a href attribute with an url. I don't understand why I can't extract it

Comment: Because the href attribute is added to the element by javascript  it does not exist in the original html, you can check by writing the text for the response html to a file and looking @rgash